# How can I plot professional quality graphs in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

The default graphs produced from matlab are very different from what I see in books. For example the image below looks visually pleasing. Can I change default settings of matlab to mimic this graphing style?
[image: -]

Comment: [Chart line appearance and behavior](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.line-properties.html)

Comment: That image looks like it is made with MATLAB or one of the tools that copy it. So I'm not sure what you are asking. Also, I don't find it visually pleasing at all, and there are many things wrong with it: The plots should be made with a line rather than markers, because the markers overlap and you can't distinguish them. The legend is redundant, and should be removed. The background grid is distracting and doesn't help reading the data. The axes have too many numbers on them, and don't have labels. Etc.

Comment: @LuisMendo: HG2 graphics look better on the screen, but EPS outputs have always been production quality. Many books have been published with beautiful graphics made in MATLAB. It is just that, like *every* other piece of software I've tried, the defaults are not good, and tweaking is necessary to make the graphs good enough.

Comment: @CrisLuengo You are totally right. Pre-HG2 graphs looked just as good on eps / pdf

Comment: @CrisLuengo, do you know why this question was closed?  The question: **Can I change default settings of MATLAB to mimic this graphic style** was not opinion-based. The answer is a resounding **yes**, you can edit the plot to match your desired style. The comment thread on visualization diverted to opinion-based discussion, but the question was not.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan: I voted to close because there are two questions (the one in the title is very different from the one in the body) that both are answered with “yes”. Such answers are not interesting for SO. If the question had been “how can I recreate the settings of the plot below”, which is the question you answered, it might have been better. Though that would have been a rather broad question that would have drawn comments like “what have you done so far?” and “please post a MCVE”, and I don’t think I would vote to reopen it.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan: Your answer is very good, it’s a pitty it’s posted under a bad question. :/

Answer (score 3):

This question will refrain from lecturing the OP on best practices for graphics and simply attempt to answer the question as asked. I personally concur with a few of the concerns raised but leave it to the OP to seek out resources on data visualization and graphical aesthetics. (For the record, I'm not a fan of the chart.)

**Resources:**

1. The [MATLAB Plot Gallery](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/plot-gallery.html) depicts a range of plots and adjustments that may help you. For high quality, professional looking graphs, scroll down to the *Advanced Plots* to see source code and the resulting figures.
2. Graphical overview of the [Types of MATLAB Plots](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/types-of-matlab-plots.html) available.
3. You can also make a basic plot then use MATLAB's Plot Editor to customize the properties through the graphical interface. When done, click **File-->Generate Code** and you'll see *one possible way* to code that graph.  This is helpful when you know how to do something through the interface but want to script it in the future.
4. Examples with code for [Publication Quality Plots with Matlab](http://steventhornton.ca/publication-quality-plots-with-matlab/)
5. Mathworks blog on [Making Pretty Graphs](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/12/11/making-pretty-graphs/)
6. Another example on [Creating high-quality graphics in MATLAB for papers and presentations](https://dgleich.wordpress.com/2013/06/04/creating-high-quality-graphics-in-matlab-for-papers-and-presentations/)

I realize some of these links may eventually expire. Please feel free to comment if they do

**Example:**
I'm no expert. I learned everything in this answer from looking at the documentation, plot source code, and playing with the properties for the various plot components.

[image: Graph demonstrating possible customizable features]

```
% Functions of Interest                     % MATLAB 2018a
fh=@(x) a + a*sin(b*x) + 1-exp(-b*x);
gh=@(x) a + (a/b)*cos(c*x);
a = 20;
b = .3;
c = .2;

% Plot
X = (0:.01:25)';
figure, hold on
p(1) = plot(X,fh(X),'r-','DisplayName','Excitation')
p(2) = plot(X,gh(X),'b-','DisplayName','Recovery')
% legend('show')    % Optional legend (omitted here since we're adding text)
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
title('Particle Displacement')

% Options
ha = gca;
box on
grid on
ylim([-80 100])
set(ha,'GridLineStyle','--')     % use ':' for dots
t(1) = text(3.5,80,'excitation')
t(2) = text(12,20,'recovery')
for k = 1:2
    p(k).LineWidth = 2.2;
    t(k).FontWeight = 'bold';
    t(k).FontSize = 12;
    t(k).FontName = 'Arial';
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function which takes a matrix of data where each row represents a signal that you want to plot.
Define some styles you want to use for plotting. In your example plot, the first two would be 'bo' and 'rx'. Just iterate over your rows and plot each row with a different style followed by the command "hold on;"

```
function fancyplot(xaxis, matrix)
    figure;
    style = {'bo', 'rx', 'k.'}; # and so on
    for r = 1:size(matrix, 1)
        plot(xaxis, matrix(r,:), style{r});
        hold on;
    end
end
```

Write another script which you execute right after you plot or add it to the function above. In this script use the the following methods to control the limits of the axis

[xlim](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html)
[ylim](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html)

Set them to the min/max values of the data you plotted.

To add text to your plots use the [Text](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/add-text-to-specific-points-on-graph.html) command.

If you want to use these plots in publications be mindful of the fact that most publications are black and white and your graphs should be distinguishable event if they are not colored (I doubt the ones above would be). I always believed doing all formatting in code is a good idea without the manual tinkering around. Otherwise you might figure out that you have to update all 8 plots in your publication at 4 am shortly before you need to submit your paper. If you run some simulations and all formatting is in code you can simply execute your formatting scripts and save the plots automatically [how to save a picture from code](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html), preferably to the eps format.